# Define custom Comparator for JavaFX TableView Column rendered as SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Table which has different columns , the signature of the one i want to add a custom comporator is this :

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Media,SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>> hasBeenPlayed;
```

So this column is rendered as an ImageView . It has two possible states , either the `Imageview` will have `null` image or the `ImageView` will have an Image , a specific one i have defined .

---

So what i want is the sorting to be based on I**f the `ImageView` has null Image and if the ImageView has Image** , so i made the below [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) but it reports an error i don't know why...

```
hasBeenPlayed.setComparator( new Comparator<SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView> o1 , SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView> o2) {
      if (o1.get().getImage() == o2.get().getImage())
         return 0;
      return -1;
   }
});
```

I should use lambda expression for the above , i added it in this way to be more obvious what i am trying to achieve.

---

The error i am getting is ..

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException:
  javafx.scene.image.ImageView cannot be cast to javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
```

---

---

---

---

---

**As James_D requested on the comments:**

Cell Value Factory:

```
hasBeenPlayed.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hasBeenPlayed"));
```

Part of the Model `Media`:

```
public abstract class Media {

 .....

 /** The has been played. */
 private SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView> hasBeenPlayed;

 .....

 /**
 * Checks for been played property.
 *
 * @return the simple object property
 */
 public SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView> hasBeenPlayedProperty() {
    return hasBeenPlayed;
 }
```

}

Comment: can you show more line of the stacktrace I suspect the error to be elsewhere...

Comment: `TableColumn<Media, SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>>` just seems wrong. This means your cell value factory is returning an `ObservableValue<SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>>`? You need to show how you have set the column up and what the cell value property is, along with the model class.

Comment: Additionally, your comparator doesn't define an ordering. You need to have `compare(x, y) > 0` whenever `compare(y, x) < 0`, which is clearly not the case here. (That's not causing the class cast exception, clearly, but it would cause problems later.)

Comment: @James_D I modified the question :) . I tried the same model changing the column to `TableColumn<Media, ImageView>` , it works the same . I don't know why though ... The comporator doesn't reports error but it doens't order though.

Comment: Please also show how you changed the comparator. What is wrong with the solution that is posted?

Comment: @James_D After i changed the column to ImageView , the Comparator doesn't reports error but also when i sort the column , Descendant/ascendant order  nothing funny happens . I want on the ascendant order all the Played Media to go at the top and on the Descendant order all the Played Media to go to the bottom. I mean the rows :) . All the nulls at the bottom and all the non null ImageView rows at the Top , like sorting 1 and 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

First of all you're putting UI elements in the item class, which is something you should avoid. The name of the column hints at the displayed property to have only 2 states. A boolean property would be more appropriate.

Use a custom `cellFactory` to display the image.

Furthermore according to the error message the real type of the column should be `TableColumn<Media, ImageView>`.

Also you're violating the contract of `Comparator` by making it non-symetric.

You have to ensure the following is fulfilled:

If `comparator.compare(a, b) < 0` then `comparator.compare(b, a) > 0`. In your case this is not fulfilled unless all `ImageView`s contain the same image (or all contain `null`).

Modify the code like this in addition to making the property a boolean property:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Media, Boolean> hasBeenPlayed;
```

---

```
hasBeenPlayed.setComparator((v1, v2) -> Boolean.compare(v1, v2));
```

or alternatively

```
hasBeenPlayed.setComparator((v1, v2) -> -Boolean.compare(v1, v2));
```

and add the following to the `initialize` method of the controller

```
final Image playedImage = new Image(...);

hasBeenPlayed.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Media, Boolean>() {
    private final ImageView image = new ImageView();

    {
        setGraphic(image);
        image.setFitWidth(playedImage.getWidth());
        image.setFitHeight(playedImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
         super.updateItem(item, empty);

         // set the image according to the played state
         image.setImage(item != null && item ? playedImage : null);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the default comparator will suffice, once the change has been made to using a `Boolean` as the column data type.

Comment: Very smart answer Fabian ! It is solving also one other problem that i have . A row is representing emotions the user feels for a song (hate , dislike , like , love) using an `ImageView` with different `Images` . I didn't knew how to implement an order for this , so love appears first etc. As i see i will use <Media,Integer> and your way :)

Comment: I get this error trying to use the code of cell factory you added `Type mismatch: cannot convert from new TableCell<Media,Boolean>(){} to ObservableValue<Boolean>`

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I assume you've used `setCellValueFactory` instead of `setCellFactory`...

Comment: Omg i am blind . Thank you Fabian , we really see with our brain and not with eyes .